# Google Chrome Extension: Webpage in Popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to creating extensions and I also don't know much about html but I have an idea for a chrome extension that should be pretty simple so if you give me a little help I may be able to do it.

I want a popup to open when the user clicks the extension-icon (like most extensions) and the popup is supposed to contain a webpage like "http://google.com". That's actually about it. I created the manifest file with the required data and thats fine, now I need to know how to make the html file contain the external webpage.
Another problem: when I tried different things in the html file the popup was tiny and just white.

I hope someone can give me hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have made an extension wich displays links to several websites.
My popup.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank>Google</a> <br/>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank>StackOverflow</a> <br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The target="blank means it opens the site in a new tab

More information about html is found here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

Be sure to make the icon 19x19 pixels,and be sure to name it in the manifest.json file
with the filename extension for example

```
"browser_action":{
"default_icon":"iconname.png",
"default_popup":"popup.html"
}
```

Comment: `target="_blank"` actually means it opens in a new window. If you've set your preferences to open new windows in a new tab, it'll do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use an `iframe` tag within your popup. I do that many times to point the user a FAQ page hosted outside.